# Face-recognition results in ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,1499,1200,3) (128,)

Tags: python, face-recognition

So I have some code looking like this for a face recognition project I am trying to do

```
import cv2
import face_recognition
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
path = 'youtube_stuff2/'
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(path+'obama.webm')
obama= face_recognition.load_image_file(path+'obama.jpg')
obama_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama)[0]
all_encoding = [obama]
images = face_recognition.load_image_file(path+'obama.jpg')
locations = face_recognition.face_locations(images)
encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(images)
#print(encodings.shape)
print(face_recognition.compare_faces([obama],encodings[0]))
```

Since they are both the same images I would expect a "True" result but instead I get this

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,1499,1200,3) (128,)
```

I don't understand why my encoding has a different shape given it is the same image. Any help on this would be appreciated. P.S the images is linked [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/President_Barack_Obama.jpg/1200px-President_Barack_Obama.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
print(face_recognition.compare_faces([obama],encodings[0]))
```

use `obama_encodings` instead of `obama`.

Comment: Thanks. Such an easy fix.